# coordinate system and coordinate functions $x^i$ are smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I was reading Semi-Riemannian Geometry with Applications to Relativity by Barrett O'Neil and it claims that:

All coordinate systems $\epsilon$ and coordinate functions $x^i$ are smooth maps on the domain of $\epsilon$. A coordinate system is also known as a chart and is a homeomorphism between an open set $U$ topological space $S$ and an open set $\epsilon(U)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For each $p \in U$, $\epsilon(p) = (x^1(p),...,x^n(p))$ and $x^i$ are coordinate functions.

But by definition, we only require the coordinate systems to be a homeomorphism. So how do we obtain smoothness?

Comment: They're smooth by definition of what it means for a map on a smooth manifold to be smooth. Smoothness is tested in charts after all.

Comment: Sorry, so are you saying that the coordinate function as a function from a manifold to the manifold $\mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth?

Comment: What Thorgott said: a function defined on (some open set of) $M$, taking values in some $\Bbb R^k$, is smooth if in coordinate charts, it looks like a smooth function (between open sets of Euclidean spaces). A chart is a function defined on an open set of $M$. What does a chart look like from its own point of view? The identity. Is the identity smooth? Yes.

Comment: Since $S$ is a priori only a topological space, there is no definition of what a smooth function of $S$ is. A coordinate function $x^i$ is smooth, if it is smooth with respect to any other coordinate system. In other words, $S$ is covered by coordinate charts, and where the coordinate charts overlap, the coordinate functions for one chart are smooth functions with respect to the coordinates of the other coordinate chart.

Comment: Ok so what I understand from all your comments is this: we define charts to be smooth so that when we test for smoothness of function $\phi$ between manifolds, the composition $\eta^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \epsilon$ makes sense as a composition of smooth functions?